# MySQL - Выборка по нескольким значениям (фильтр, все условия выборки)

Tags: mysql, laravel, querybuilder

подскажите куда копнуть что-бы фильтр корректно заработал.

Так вот, мне нужно что-бы при выборке выполнялись все условия т.е. выбрать только те элементы из таблицы у которых жанры **fantastika** и **skola** если у нас есть элемент с жанром **fantastika** но у него нет жанра **skola** то он в выборку не попадает.

Массив жанров (приходит из формы):

```
array:2 [
  0 => "fantastika"
  1 => "skola"
]
```

Мой класс **ItemsFetcher.php** для выборки данных

```php
public function all(Filter $filter): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $all = CategoryItems::query();

        if ($genres = $filter->genres) {
            $all->whereHas('genres', function (Builder $query) use ($genres) {
                $query->join('category_item_genres', 'category_item_genres.id', '=', 'category_items_item_genres.genre_id');
                $query->whereIn('slug', $genres);
            });
        }

        return $all->with(
            'kind'
        )->paginate(20);
    }
```

Попытки написать sql запрос

```sql
where exists (select *
              from `category_items_item_genres`
              inner join `category_item_genres`
              on `category_item_genres`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`genre_id`
              where `category_items`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`item_id`
              and `category_item_genres`.`slug` in ('fantastika','skola')
              )
```

Смотрел решения в сети но так и не получилось реализовать ;(

Comment: попробуйте изучить `GROUP BY` и `HAVING`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7242646/12593651

Comment: ```
select *
from `category_items`
where exists (select *
              from `category_items_item_genres`
              inner join `category_item_genres`
              on `category_item_genres`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`genre_id`
              where `category_items`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`item_id`
              and `category_item_genres`.`slug` = 'fantastika'
              and `category_item_genres`.`slug` = 'mexa'
              )
```
Добавляю ещё один and и результат 0 ;(

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось, работу свою выполняет но может кто-то сделает маленький рефакторинг ;)
Laravel - класс **ItemsFetcher.php**

```php
public function all(Filter $filter): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $all = CategoryItems::query();

        if ($genres = $filter->genres) {
            $all->whereHas('genres', function (Builder $query) use ($genres) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*)'));
                $query->join('category_item_genres', 'category_item_genres.id', '=', 'category_items_item_genres.genre_id');
                $query->whereIn('category_item_genres.slug', $genres);
                $query->groupBy('category_items.id');
                $query->havingRaw('(COUNT(*)=' . count($genres) . ')');
            });
        }

        return $all->with(
            'kind'
        )->paginate(20);
    }
```

sql который у меня получился

```
select *
from `category_items`
where exists (select COUNT(*)
              from `category_items_item_genres`
              inner join `category_item_genres`
              on `category_item_genres`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`genre_id`
              where `category_items`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`item_id`
              and `category_item_genres`.`slug` in ('skola','fentezi')
              GROUP BY `category_items`.`id`
              HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 2)
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
select *
from `category_items`
join (select `category_items_item_genres`.`item_id`
      from `category_items_item_genres`
      inner join `category_item_genres`
        on `category_item_genres`.`id` = `category_items_item_genres`.`genre_id`
           and `category_item_genres`.`slug` in ('skola','fentezi')
      GROUP BY `category_items_item_genres`.`item_id`
      HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 2)
      ) g
on (`category_items`.id = g.`item_id`)
```